# Flutter path_provider issue

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec, flutter-path

I upgraded flutter and dart recently and unexpectedly encountered this error. Everything was fine, I just re-started the project and the error was there!

**Error:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My pubspec.yml dependencies:

```
 dependencies:
  auto_animated: any
  awesome_dialog: ^2.1.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  circular_countdown_timer: ^0.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  dropdown_search: ^2.0.1
  dropdownfield: ^1.0.3
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.10.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_animator: ^3.2.0
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: any
  flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  flutter_tags: ^0.4.9+1
  flutter_zoom_drawer: ^2.1.1
  google_fonts: any
  http: ^0.13.1
  image: ^3.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  image_size_getter: ^1.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: 4.0.5955
  mime: ^1.0.0
  page_transition: ^1.0.9
  progress_indicators: ^1.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  swipe_cards: ^0.1.0
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^19.3.56
  textfield_tags: ^1.1.1
  upgrader: ^3.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  open_file: ^3.1.0
```

What I've tried:

- flutter upgrade
- Flutter clean and flutter get
- Changing min SDK version

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I reinstalled flutter and created a project from scratch and copied my older code. Also, Firebase is now only compatible if you have the min SDK version of 19.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by upgrading the AndroidStudio Version，It maybe caused by the low  version of development tool，